# MapFragment not available in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am new to Android. I am trying to create model app which requires `Google Maps`.

- I am using `activity_main.xml` to get the map.
- I am trying to drag-and-drop fragment from palette and when I do it I cannot find the `MapFragment` class option.

Actually I inserted code for getting the `MapFragment` into the fragment and I got it. But I just want to know why `MapFragment` is not available in Fragment.

Please help me how to find it. And I don't know whether `activity_main.xml` is fine to get the map or should I create a new activity with fragment.

Please give your suggestions and guide me to get `Google Maps` into my model project. Thank you :)

Comment: post your code with xml file.

Comment: **activity_main.xml**

Comment: i dont need file names just post whatever you have write in activity main.xml and in your main fragment.

Comment: @jaydroider ya bro I trying to put my code here but stackoverflow is not allowing me to post the code :(